# Cookie value is empty after navigating to second page

Tags: typescript, testing, cookies, automated-tests, testcafe

I have 2 domains. Some action done on the first one results in setting the same cookie on both of them. I need to read the value of this cookie on both domains. The problem is that however this is possible on the first one, after navigating to the second one, the cookie is present but its value is empty.

Why?

Here's the code to get the cookie value:

```
const getCookie = ClientFunction(() => {
    const name = 'ConfigCookie';
    const match = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(name + '=([^;]+)'));
    let decodedValue;
    if (match) decodedValue = decodeURIComponent(match[1]).replace(/%28/g, '(').replace(/%29/g, ')');
    return JSON.parse(decodedValue || '');
})
```

And here's the code of the test (I removed sensitive data)

```
test('xyz', async t => {
    await t
        .navigateTo(FirstDomain)
        .click(firstDomainSubmitButtonSelector)
        const firstDomainCookie = await getCookie();
        const firstDomainConsents = firstDomainCookie.consents;
    await t
        .expect(consents).eql({here the expected value});
    await t
        .navigateTo(SecondDomain)
        const secondDomainCookie = await getCookie();
        const secondDomainConsents = secondDomainCookie.consents;
        console.log(secondDomainConsents)
})
```

Comment: As far as I remember it's security related, e.g JS could only read cookie info from the domain/site its running on. Otherwise any malicious code could read cookie contents of anything

Answer (score 1):

I created a code snippet with a TestCafe test showing the behavior you described. The test is green on my side. Could you please change the test to show the problematic behavior and share the code of the corrected test so that I can reproduce the issue on my side?

```js
import { Selector, ClientFunction } from 'testcafe';
 
fixture`test fixture`
const FirstDomain = 'http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example';
const SecondDomain = 'https://wikipedia.org/';
test('test name', async t => {
    const setCookie = ClientFunction(() => {
        document.cookie = 'key=value'
    });
    const getCookie = ClientFunction(() => {
        return document.cookie;
    });
    const data = 'key=value'
    await t.navigateTo(FirstDomain)
    await setCookie()
    await t.expect(await getCookie(data)).ok()
    await t.navigateTo(SecondDomain)
    await setCookie()
    await t.expect(await getCookie()).ok(data)
    await t.navigateTo(FirstDomain).click(await Selector('#submit-button'))
    await t.expect(await getCookie()).ok(data)
    await t.navigateTo(SecondDomain)
    await t.expect(await getCookie()).ok(data)
})
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your answer. In the snippet you provided I see that you are first setting the cookie, then reading it. The problem in my case is that I do not need to set the cookie. The cookie is being set by our frontend library on both of these domains (triggered by some action done on the first one).
When I'm debugging the test in the debugger mode, I can see that cookie is indeed set on both domains, but the value of this cookie is only present on the first one. I have read that this might be connected with CORS. Also, maybe the fact that this cookie is SameSite-Lax has sth to do here?

Comment: Klaudia, thank you for the detailed explanation. Unfortunately, I cannot help you with this issue without reproducing it on my side. Could you please share any test that demonstrates the problem? I will try to help if the issue is related to the TestCafe framework.